Issues with using EventToCommandBehavior in .Net Maui
The issue that I am having is that the Name property length is always 0 no matter how many characters I type in the Entry Control. The TextChanged event is firing because when I type a character execution breaks at the NameChanged RelayCommand, but again the Name property does not change. Am I missing something?
XAML
<Entry Placeholder="Enter Name" MaxLength="15">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="TextChanged"
            Command="{Binding NameChangedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>

ViewModel
[ObservableProperty]
string _name=string.Empty;

[RelayCommand]
private void NameChanged()
{

if (Name.Length >=3)
   IsNameLengthValid=true;
else
   IsNameLengthValid=false;
}

[RelayCommand(CanExecute=nameof(IsNameLengthValid))]
async Task Submit()
{
await Toast.Make("Form Submitted").Show().ConfigureAwait(false);
}


your Entrys Text property is not bound to Name

Thanks !!! Let me try that. I was following along with a tutorial and nothing was mentioned about that. Maybe it was assumed but in .Net Maui I don't want to assume anything.

You can try to set <Entry Placeholder="Enter Name" MaxLength="15" Text="{Binding Name}"> in XMAL code, and then add a new property in ViewModel:`[ObservableProperty]
string _name = string.Empty;
public string Name
{
get => _name;
set
{
SetProperty(ref _name, value);
}
} By this way, when the text in the Entry changes, _name` in ViewModel
Properties are updated accordingly.

@JSmith You should never assume anything, if you're unsure, always check and confirm. You indeed need to bind to Name: Text="{Binding Name}", that property already exists because it's auto-generated by the [ObservableProperty] source generator.

As Jason said, the Text property of Entry in the code is not bound to the _name Property in the ViewModel, so you can refer to the following xaml code to make adjustments:
<Entry Placeholder="Enter Name" MaxLength="15" Text="{Binding Name}">

In addition, in ViewModel, add a new Name property in [ObservableProperty] and set the corresponding SetProperty and GetProperty in it:
[ObservableProperty]
string _name = string.Empty;

public string Name
{
     get => _name;
     set
     {
         SetProperty(ref _name, value);
     }
}

By this way, when the text in the Entry changes, the "_name" in the ViewModel property is updated accordingly.

At least the second part of your answer is incorrect. [ObservableProperty] will auto-generate the Name property; the code you presented here won't compile.

Just remove the second part of your answer, and it should be fine.
